# Reducing seek times when reading many small files

Tags: linux, language-agnostic, filesystems

I need to write some code (in any language) to process 10,000 files that reside on a local Linux filesystem. Each file is ~500KB in size, and consists of fixed-size records of 4KB each.

The processing time per record is negligible, and the records can be processed in any order, both within and across different files.

A naïve implementation would read the files one by one, in some arbitrary order. However, since my disks are very fast to read but slow to seek, this will almost certainly produce code that's bound by disk seeks.

Is there any way to code the reading up so that it's bound by disk throughput rather than seek time?

One line of inquiry is to try and get an approximate idea of where the files reside on disk, and use that to sequence the reads. However, I am not sure what API could be used to do that.

I am of course open to any other ideas.

The filesystem is ext4, but that's negotiable.

Comment: Why use multiple files ? You could use only one big file with fixed records and group sizes ?

Comment: How exactly will these files be processed?

Comment: @ydroneaud: I have no control of how the files are produced, and merging them as a pre-processing step would raise exactly the same question (i.e. *in what order* should they be read during the merge to get a decent performance?)

Comment: @HarHaHu: I don't think that matters. Let's say I need to count the number of 4K blocks that contain the letter `A`.

Comment: BTW: it's only 5GB. You could start by copying them to a local disk. (maybe in parallel)

Comment: @wildplasser: They *are* on a local RAID array. In total, there are 1000 datasets like the one described in the question.

Comment: Then: prefetch! (if you can determine the order in advance, that is)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could do the reads by scheduling all of them in quick succession with [aio_read](http://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_read). That would put all reads in the filesystem read queue at once, and then the filesystem implementation is free to complete the reads in a way that minimizes seeks.

Comment: Aio_read needs a file descriptor. And it's probably the open() or the first read() that is slow.

Comment: @Wildplasser: I can see how walking the directory structure in `open` can be slow, but is that really a problem if the files are in a limited number of directories? Once a file in the same directory has been opened, subsequent files should open quickly because most or all of the disk data required to open them has been cached, right?

Comment: The OP mentions nothing about directory structure. If there are multiple files per directory, one could assume the directory cache + inode cache would speed up everything except the first reference. But his "seek time is very long" statement is very vague. Safe approach is to consider the files randomly scattered all over the file system.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple approach, although no results guaranteed. Open as many of the files at once as you can and read all of them at once - either using threads or asynchronous I/O. This way  the disk scheduler knows what you read and can reduce the seeks by itself. **Edit:** as *wildplasser* observes, parallel `open()` is probably only doable using threads, not async I/O.

The alternative is to try to do the heavy lifting yourself. Unfortunately this involves a difficult step - getting the mapping of the files to physical blocks. There is no standard interface to do that, you could probably extract the logic from something like [ext2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) or the kernel FS driver. And this involves reading the  physical device underlying a mounted filesystem, which can be writing to it at the same time you're trying to get a consistent snapshot.

Once you get the physical blocks, just order them, reverse the mapping back to the file offsets and execute the reads in the physical block order.

Comment: This will not accelerate the overall process. It is the open() or the read of the first block that blocks the process.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the two ideas and for the link to e2fsprogs.

Comment: @wildplasser You have schedule all the `open()` calls in parallel, then the scheduler has the chance to optimize seek times between the first blocks of each file.

Comment: That's what I said. And *in parallel* implies multiple processes or threads.

Comment: @wildplasser Edited answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

could you recommend using a SSD for the file storage? that should reduce seek times greatly as there's no head to move.

Comment: Nice idea, but prohibitively expensive for the problem at hand (what I've outlined in my question is a tiny fraction of the overall dataset).

Comment: There are mechanisms, both in hardware and in software, which use a small SSD as a cache for the HDD. I haven't used any in practice, but I saw a benchmark somewhere (not by the manufacturer) where they measured performance for some mySQL workloads and found such caches quite effective even if the SSD was quite small compared to the HDD.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski: True, but the problem of reading the data from the HDD remains.

Comment: @aix Yes, but it may be reduced quite a bit since the caching mechanism is likely to prefetch data in larger blocks, meaning more continuous reads and less seeks. Of course, results will depend on the particular workload (whether the seeks are within the data which got prefetched).

Answer (score 0):

Since operations are similar and data are independent you can try using a thread pool to submit jobs that work on a number of files (can be a single file). Then you can have an idle thread complete a single job. This might help overlapping IO operations with execution.

Comment: The processing is so simple that it requires an infinitesimal amount of time. Therefore overlapping it with I/O would sadly be of no help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to keep the original program, but fork an extra process which has no other task than to prefetch the files, and prime the disk buffer cache. ( a unix/linux system uses all "free" memory as disk buffer).

The main task will stay a few files behind (say ten). The hard part would be to keep things synchronised. A pipe seems the obvious way to accomplish this.

UPDATE:

Pseudo code for the main process:

1. - fetch filename from worklist
   - if empty goto 2.
   - (maybe) fork a worker process or thread
   - add to prefetch queue
   - add to internal queue
   - if fewer than XXX items on internal queue goto 1
2. - fetch filename from internal queue
   - process it
   - goto 1

For the slave processes:

- fetch from queue
- if empty: quit
- prefetch file
- loop or quit

For the queue, a message queue seems most appropiate, since it maintains message boundaries. Another way would be to have one pipe per child (in the fork() case) or use mutexes (when using threads).

You'll need approximate seektime_per_file / processing_time_per_file worker threads / processes.

As a simplification: if seeking the files is not required (only sequential access), the slave processes could consist of the equivalent of

```
dd if=name bs=500K
```

, which could be wrapped into a popen() or a pipe+fork().

Comment: In this setup the prefetcher would be seek-bound, so the overall time needed to process the files would not improve.

Comment: You could use more prefetchers, and let them suck the same command- pipe.

Comment: I really don't see how that would help with the disk seeks. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "slow to seek". If (once opened) all the "sequential" reads will be fast (for instance: a tape-robot) You'll need multiple prefetch threads/processes. For a network-disk there would be no difference between random read and sequential read, and consequently *every* read would imply a seek.